# Character Mesh Acting Weird At Wrist [Details in Description]

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, subdivision-surface

I've been following Rainhet's 3D modeling tutorial on YouTube and it's been going smoothly with a few bumps in the road here and there. You can find the series here if it is helpful in any way: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ9OSE5BiGR-UTk47GEydSw

**My current problem is at the wrist of my character model.**

I'm unsure of when this issue occurred because it seemed fine until I tried resizing the wrist. I tried undoing the resize, but the vertex never went back to its original state. This is what the problem looks like:
[image: Picture of 3D Model without Mesh, Showing Wrist Complication]
[image: Picture of 3D Model with Mesh, Wrist Complication Circled in Red]
[image: Close-Up Picture from Inside of 3D Model with Mesh, Wrist Complication Circled in Red]
[image: Farther Away Picture from Inside of 3D Model with Mesh, Wrist Complication Circled in Red]

Here is the project file containing just the arm:
https://pasteall.org/media/f/7/f724f7caebe87902e6eda165def368ad.blend

*(Thank you for the suggestion, moonboots!)*

I saved a new file and tried removing and reattaching the arm, but I think because I've already subdivided the figure, it's too complicated for that to go over well with Blender. I might be approaching it from the wrong direction, but I'm open to any suggestions or resources the community might have. If you need more information, please let me know and I'll be happy to update this post as soon as I can. Thank you in advance for any assistance, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hello, maybe share your object (at least this part)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I didn't even realize I had this option. https://pasteall.org/media/f/7/f724f7caebe87902e6eda165def368ad.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the modifier's visibility so that you can see the mesh as it is without any *Subdivision Surface* effect. As you can see the topology is quite messy, you must have worked on it with the modifier visibility on, so you were unable to see it, you need to fix that in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Comment: Oh jeez!! Yeah, that's really bad, wow. I didn't know if messing with the visibility of the subdivision would cause problems - for some reason the language I had heard surrounding it made it feel like doing that after making changes with it on would cause a lot more problems. Thank you for taking the time to help!